# Puzzle: construct a permutation with the smallest order

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, permutations

I wonder if there is a quick logical way to solve the following, or simplify the following problem:

Say I have three (or more) identity matrices of different sizes ($I_m = m\times m$, $I_n= n\times n$, $I_q=q\times q$).
With these, I can construct a $(m+n+q) \times (m+n+q)$ block permutation matrix. For example:
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & I_n & 0\\
I_m & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 &I_q
\end{bmatrix}

A trivial solution is:
\begin{bmatrix}
I_m & 0 & 0\\
0 & I_n & 0\\
0 & 0 &I_q
\end{bmatrix}
which is an identity matrix. How do we construct a permutation matrix with the next smallest order, just by looking at the values of $m$, $n$, and $q$?

More advanced question: can we rank all possible block permutation matrices based on their orders? (again, just by inspecting the sizes of the identity matrices).

Comment: Conjecture. Put all but the smallest two blocks on the diagonal and the last two in opposite corners of a square submatrix of the right size. Then the order is what you get for that submatrix,

Comment: @EthanBolker I like your conjecture; that gives an order equal to the size of the second-smallest value (if I'm doing my thinking right) and it seems unlikely that you can do better. I was originally thinking there was an LCM effect but I don't think there is at this point.

Comment: Can the blocks be the same size, or must they be distinct? If they must be distinct, I think you cannot make a permutation matrix of size 2.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I want to consider some specific cases too (e.g. $m=n$). To generalize your point, I realized that if the sum of the dimensions of some identity matrices equal to the sum of the dimensions of some other identity matrices, the order of permutation can be as small as 2. Are there other straightforward cases?

Comment: Simulposted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406835/puzzle-construct-a-permutation-with-the-smallest-order without notice to either site. That's an abuse, CWC.

Comment: @GerryMyerson My apologies. I wasn't aware that is not allowed.